# How can I get autorun to work with runInAction, using mobx?

Tags: javascript, typescript, observable, mobx

Trying to learn mobx and runInAction, but struggling to understand why autorun is not invoking my callback in the following example:

```
class FooClass {

    // constructor() {
    //     this.fooMethod();
    // }

    @observable myBool = false;

    async fooMethod() {

        await new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, 1000));
        runInAction(() => this.myBool = true); // <--- myBool: true is never logged to the console. why?
        await new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, 3000));
        runInAction(() => this.myBool = false); // <--- also not logged
    }
}

let foo = new FooClass();

foo.fooMethod();
autorun(() => console.log("myBool:", foo.myBool));
```

Using TypeScript and babel with decorators.

As I understand it, runInAction(...) can be used if you want to change some observables when you are not inside a method which is marked as an action?

Why is my script not working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are probably using MobX v6 and its api changed a little bit, you now need to add `makeAutoObservable` or `makeObservable` call inside constructor, like that:

```
import { autorun, makeAutoObservable, observable, runInAction } from 'mobx';

class FooClass {
  constructor() {
    makeAutoObservable(this);

    autorun(() => console.log('myBool:', this.myBool));
    this.fooMethod();
  }

  // You can actually remove decorator here if you use `makeAutoObservable`
  @observable myBool = false;

  async fooMethod() {
    await new Promise((r) => setTimeout(r, 1000));
    runInAction(() => (this.myBool = true)); // it will be logged now
    await new Promise((r) => setTimeout(r, 3000));
    runInAction(() => (this.myBool = false)); // it will be logged now too
  }
}

new FooClass();
```

[Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/httpsstackoverflowcomquestions68104470-r67cu)

[More info in the docs](https://mobx.js.org/observable-state.html)

Comment: yikes! how did i miss that. added makeObservable, not makeAutoObservable ;)

Comment: `makeAutoObservable` is even better, in my opinion! You can drop decorators and everything will work automatically. But choose whatever fits you

Comment: only want those explicitly marked with a decorator. otherwise i dont think i need the decorators :)